# Javascript sees my nested array as an object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to send a nested PHP array to Javascript. But Javascript parses the top level as an object.

> The Teams array should contain 2 other arrays with each 2 team names

*As you can see in the screenshot and the json, the "Teams" is an object.*

```
"teams":{"1":["test","test"],"2":["test","test"]},"results":[]}
```

[image]

This is the code I'm using to build up the nested array

```
$iterator = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $competition->teams->count(); $i++) {
    if($i % 2 == 0) {
        $iterator++;
    }
    $data["teams"][$iterator][] = "test";
}
```

The funny thing is, it is working when the array is not multidimensional.
For example the following example doesn't return Teams as an object.

[image]

I'm guessing if I remove the array keys it might work, but It's impossible to have a nested array without array keys, right?

#### Any idea what I might be doing wrong? And how I can get Javascript to just see my nested array without seeing it as an object.

Thank you!

Comment: please add the object as JSON string with spacer to the question.

Comment: What does "with spacer" mean? Should I include the complete json in the code?

Comment: it is named as `space` here: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), it makes good readable object structure in text form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one problem with your code, `$iterator` always starts with value `1` so `json_encode` function uses JSON object to preserve that index.

Everything changes when you start indexing your array from `0` instead.

```
$test = array(
    1 => 'test'
);

echo json_encode($test);
```

Shows `{"1":"test"}` which is an object.

```
$test = array(
    0 => 'test'
);

echo json_encode($test);
```

Shows `["test"]` which is an array.

Comment: Wow! You're right, changing the $iterator to -1 and it's all working now.